# Pass codeigniter $data['foo'] from controller to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code

```
 public function delete($delete_candindate){
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->dbforge();
    $delete_candindate = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->dbforge->drop_table($delete_candindate);
    $this->db->where('dataset_name', $delete_candindate);
    $this->db->delete('all_datasets'); 
    $data['success_or_failure'] = 'That dataset already exists.Kindly go back and try again.';
    $this->load->view('success_or_failure');
    }
```

which i am using to delete some data from my tables but i now need to pass data from the controller to the view but my controller has a parameter.

Somehow,the variable `$data['success_or_failure']`  is not being passed since i keep getting this error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: success_or_failure
>
> Filename: views/success_or_failure.php
>
> Line Number: 54

Why isn't `$data['success_or_failure'] = 'That dataset already exists.Kindly go back and try again.';` being passed to the view?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that i was not passing the `$data` variable

`public function delete($delete_candindate){
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->dbforge();
    $delete_candindate = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->dbforge->drop_table($delete_candindate);
    $this->db->where('dataset_name', $delete_candindate);
    $this->db->delete('all_datasets'); 
    $data['success_or_failure'] = 'That dataset already exists.Kindly go back and try again.';
    $this->load->view('success_or_failure',$data);
    }`